# How to set mesh size to fit the viewport height and screen in three.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/canvas-lighting-experiment-wip-3p9im?file=/src/Canvas.component.jsx

I have already set the canvas to fit the window's height and width, however, the mesh inside the scene is not filling the screen completely.

I have tried playing with the camera position of the scene to fill the viewport but that doesn't work responsively.

How to set the mesh size to fill the viewport completely and responsively?

Comment: When the viewport changes shape, how do you want the mesh to look? Should it stretch or cover or something else?

Comment: Ideally would stretch

Comment: The most important bit is the light source should stay at the top right of the screen while the plane resizes to fit the viewport...

Comment: Ok, in that case you need to move the light source to the frustum corner. You can see how it’s done here (inside update(), using Vector3.unproject). Then do the same but for the plane corners. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/helpers/CameraHelper.js

Comment: Codesandbox: "Something went wrong. Sandbox not found"

Answer (score 1):

I think I had replied this one in the other post. Anyway, just create the `PlaneBufferGeometry` based on the clientHeight and clientWidth and with a factor based on the POV distance (I calculated quickly 135 as factor, but you can play with it)...

```
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(container.clientWidth/135, container.clientHeight/135, 1, 1)
```

I didn't test too much, but it works well at any resolution I tested...
[image]